# Casbah: How to Update and Embedded Object When Field Names Have Spaces?

Tags: mongodb, casbah

Supposing I had the following document in a database:

```
{"_id":"test", "with space":{"a name":1}}
```

How can I write a $set query in Casbah to update "with space"."a name" to 2?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
collection.update(MongoDBObject("_id" -> "test"), "'with space'.'a name'" $set 2)
```

But what if my field names were unknown and I had to compose them at runtime? Is there any way to "escape" them in a safe way? (For example, what if any of them contains single quotes, etc.)

Comment: I think you should probably change your schema to use standardized key names, and user input goes in the value part of the data. This makes querying/aggregation easier in the end, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any explicit escaping required for MongoDB; you can just pass a variable name, eg:

```
 val key = MongoDBObject(name + '.' + embeddedname -> "somevalue")
```

or

```
 val key = MongoDBObject("with space.a name" -> "somevalue")
```

While MongoDB does allow you to use any valid UTF-8 character in key names aside from '.' and a leading '$', you would generally be best sticking to alphanumeric key names plus underscore.

If you are concerned about safety of user-provided input, see [How does MongoDB address SQL or Query injection?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection)

Comment: You and Wes make a good point. I guess the visual aspect of the space played some trick on me and I forgot that it is "just another character" which should cause no ambiguity in recognising the period separator. +1 for both. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about not putting spaces in your field names. Seriously.

Ok, if you really must, it should work fine without escaping...

```
collection.update(MongoDBObject("_id" -> "test"), $set ("with space.a name" -> 2))
```

Comment: Single quotes are valid parts of a key, so they'll work fine (if they're part of the key).